# How can use Tab to navigate completion list

Tags: autocompletion, navigation, plugin-coc, original-vim, snippets

I use both `coc.nvim` and `Ultisnip` for completion in vim.

`coc-snippet` does not support some feature in `Ultisnip` so I use `Ultisnip` instead

But I have a problem is `<Tab>` for trigger completion in `Ultisnip` override `coc.nvim` thus I cannot use tab in `coc.nvim` to navigate. Any idea for this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right UltiSnips overrides the command so change the keybindings of UltiSnips

```
let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger='<C-Tab>'
```

for example

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Just a note that `<C-Tab>` may not work on all terminals or configurations, since `<Tab>` is indistinguishable from `<C-i>` in some configurations (see `:help <Tab>`)